# File not visible in Finder

Tags: terminal, finder

I've saved a file with the name `filename\.svg` and it didn't appear in finder. When I check terminal, there was a file named `.svg` in the folder I saved my file. I changed its name to `test.svg` but it still doesn't appear in Finder. Here is a screenshot from terminal:

[image: Terminal ls output]

How can I make this file visible in Finder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make only this specific file visible in Finder, try the following command using `Terminal.app` from *Applications > Utilities*:

```
$ cd /path-to-folder/where/invisible-file/is-located/
$ chflags nohidden ./test.svg
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice.  I was just about to add that to my answer.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` for `chflags`. Except for the target file permissions.

Answer (score 4):

From [this tutorial on MacWorld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/), here is a way to show hidden files in the Finder:

Open a terminal, and enter this command at the Bash prompt:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Then restart the Finder with the following command (also from terminal):

```
$ killall Finder
```

The next time you open a Finder window, your hidden files should be visible.

To echo what Oliver said, you can also use `chflags` to alter the "hidden" property on a specific file. ([chflags man page](http://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html))

```
chflags nohidden hiddenfile.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug in Finder. To make that file visible you need to re-start the finder as follows:

Press COMMAND+OPTION+ESC then select Finder and click on Relaunch.